# I want to crop one image and append it to another in VB before displaying the final result in Access

Tags: vba, image-processing, background-process, ms-access-2016

I have an Access database of my paperback book collection that uses VB to download and save barcode files from a free online service. The script saves them as .png files, and I display them as image objects within my forms and reports (I figure if my books got lost, stolen or destroyed having the ISBN and/or UPC codes to identify the books can help in determining the value of the loss).

There's a specific barcode that can't be generated by the website- but I can make it myself by downloading two barcode images, cropping one, appending it to the second image, then saving the result as a third image. After that the downloaded images can be discarded (deleted) and the resulting composite image can be used as an image object in my Access forms and reports.

ImageA.png is 688 x 209 pixels in size (it is referred to as an ISBN 13+5 barcode, with a 13-digit EAN-style barcode on the left and a 5-digit price barcode on the right).

ImageB.png is 471 x 209 pixels in size (this is a standard 12-digit UPC-A barcode found on everything from DVDs to hand sanitizer dispensers to whiskey bottles to car batteries).

What I want to do in VB is to crop 450 pixels from the left side of ImageA, effectively stripping the EAN code from the image, then saving the 238 x 209 pixels that are left as either ImageA.png or TempA.png ... Then I want to append that to the right side of ImageB.png and save the combined image as ImageC.png (709 x 209 pixels). The combined action effectively takes the "EAN + 5" barcode image, strips the EAN code off, then replaces it with the UPC code.

It might be easier to understand what I want to do by viewing this: [Step-by-step graphical example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0amH.png)

After I have ImageC.png saved, ImageA.png and/or TempA.png and ImageB.png can be deleted. As all I really want is ImageC.png.

I wish I could provide sample code but everywhere I look I see code samples that show Picture Boxes or require mouse movement- The downloaded images will always be the same size all the time, so I just want to load and crop the image without displaying it... then append it to the 2nd image  and save it... *then* I want to display the resulting composite image.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Okay maybe let's simplify this a bit... Ignore what I said about barcodes and let's go with just "I have a .png image of a known and consistent size (688 pixels x 209 pixels) and I want to remove/crop 450 pixels from the left side...  then save what's left (an image that's 238 pixels x 209 pixels) in place of the original file or as a new file."  I'd prefer this to be done in memory (a background process) rather than displayed in a PictureBox.  I've seen info regarding the merging of images that I can try, so the cropping of the first image is what I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it...

```
    ShortISBN = Mid((LongISBNString), 5, 5)        'sets 5-digit string for filename
    ShortISBNFile = [ShortISBN] & ".png"                      'sets the new filename
    Set IP = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")                    'create WIA objects
    Set Img = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    Img.LoadFile CurrentProject.Path & "\temp.png"            'load downloaded image
    IP.Filters.Add IP.FilterInfos("Crop").FilterID                'setup crop filter
    With IP.Filters(1)
        .Properties("Left") = 450
    End With
    Set Img = IP.Apply(Img)                                            'apply change
    Img.SaveFile CurrentProject.Path & [ShortISBNFile] 'save image with new filename
    Kill CurrentProject.Path & "\temp.png"                  'delete downloaded image
```

As for merging two images, https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?725361-RESOLVED-merge-two-scanned-images-into-one seemed to have the answer, but the code was formatted differently and threw an error when I copied and pasted it verbatim into my project... but with a bit of fiddling I reformatted the code to reflect the format used in the cropping code which seemed to correct that error:

```
    Dim oIF1 As Object, oIF2 As Object, oVectNew As Object, oIFNew As Object
    Dim oIP As Object, TempCodeFile As String, lPixelsWide As Long, lPixelsHigh As Long
    ShortISBN = Mid([ISBN Number], 7, 5)
    ShortISBNFile = Mid([ISBN Number], 7, 5) & ".png"
    Set oIF1 = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    With oIF1
        .LoadFile CurrentProject.Path & [UPCCodeFile]
        lPixelsWide = .Width
        lPixelsHigh = .Height
    End With
    Set oIF2 = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    With oIF2
        .LoadFile CurrentProject.Path & [ShortISBNFile]
        lPixelsWide = lPixelsWide + .Width
    End With
    With New BmpGen                    'This is the Class Module from the above link 
         Set oVectNew = CreateObject("WIA.Vector")
         oVectNew.BinaryData = .MakeMono(BG_COLOR, lPixelsWide, lPixelsHigh)
    End With
    Set oIFNew = oVectNew.ImageFile
    Set oVectNew = Nothing
    Set oIP = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess") 'create WIA objects        
    With oIP
        oIP.Filters.Add oIP.FilterInfos("Stamp").FilterID
        With oIP.Filters(1)            
            Set .Properties("ImageFile") = oIF1
            .Properties("Left") = 0
            .Properties("Top") = 0
        End With        
        oIP.Filters.Add oIP.FilterInfos("Stamp").FilterID
        With oIP.Filters(2)
            Set .Properties("ImageFile") = oIF2
            .Properties("Left") = oIF1.Width
            .Properties("Top") = 0
        End With
        Set oIFNew = oIP.Apply(oIFNew)
    End With
    TempCodeFile = left([UPCCodeFile], 15) & " " & [ShortISBNFile]
    UPCCodeFile = TempCodeFile
    oIFNew.SaveFile CurrentProject.Path & [UPCCodeFile]
    Kill CurrentProject.Path & [ShortISBNFile]
```

I should put some error checking into the code generation process (what if the UPC code string is too short or too long?) but in the end it's amazing what you can do when you honestly have no idea what you're doing.